# Object of class could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to write phpunit test for save method at my repository. My repo code is:

```
public function saveCustomer(Custom $custom)
{
    try
    {
        $custom->save();

        return array(
            'status' => true,
            'customerId' => $custom->getId()
        );
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return array(
            'status' => false,
            'customerId' => 0
        );
    }
 }
```

I wrote this test:

```
public function testSaveNewUye()
{
    $request = array(
        'email' => 'www@www.com',
        'phone' => '555 555 555',
        'password' => '34636'
    );
    $repo = new CustomerRepository();
    $result_actual = $this->$repo->saveCustomer($request);
    $result_expected = array(
        'status' => true,
        'customerId' => \DB::table('custom')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first() + 1
    );
    self::assertEquals($result_expected, $result_actual);
}
```

I got the error given below:

> ErrorException: Object of class App\CustomerRepository could not be converted to int

Can you help me?

Comment: Nitpick: This is not a unit test, it's an integration test becaue you don't mock the database stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
$repo = new CustomerRepository();
$result_actual = $this->$repo->saveCustomer($request);
```

You are assigning and using variables not the same.

Try like this instead:

```
$this->repo = new CustomerRepository();
//     ^------- assign to `$this`
$result_actual = $this->repo->saveCustomer($request);
//                      ^------- remove `$`
```

When doing `$this->$repo->` PHP tries to convert the (object) `$repo` to a string `$this->(object)->` which does not work.

Then you have a second error here:

`\DB::table('custom')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first() + 1`

From the database you get an object (instanceof `stdClass`) which you cannot simply `+ 1`.

The whole thing is probably something like

```
\DB::table('custom')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first()->id + 1
```

(From the returned object, you want the property `id`.)

Comment: I tried but it says;Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int